# Upgraded Debian Stable (Jessie) desktop not connecting to wired Internet

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet, dhcp, internet

I updated my Debian Jessie installation a few days ago to the current minor version (8.3), which included a new Linux kernel (`uname -a` gives `3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux`). Since then, I haven't been able to connect to the Internet, which previously had not been a problem. The same ethernet cable and port quickly connects to the Internet (using DHCP) if I plug it into a Macbook or even an ancient CentOS machine, so the problem must be in the Debian configuration. I'm at a loss for what to do though. I tried different combinations of DHCP or static IP (using the IP address and settings obtained with DHCP on the other machines), and `ifupdown` or `network-manager`, along with several reboots, all to no avail. DHCP fails either silently or with a message about not obtaining a lease. With a static IP, the ethernet device shows up as connected, but in fact there is no connection to the Internet. Any ideas for how to go about troubleshooting?

Edit: Here are the lines that seem possibly relevant in `/var/log/dmesg` [`eth1` is the right port]:

```
[ 16.480813] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 18.031149] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth1: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[ 18.031151] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth1: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[ 18.031881] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[ 28.240006] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

Output of `nmcli -p -f general device show eth1`:

```
===============================================================================
                             Device details (eth1)
===============================================================================
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (Precision T5400)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               5754-v3.24
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:21:9B:41:28:86
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:08:00.0/net/eth1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth1
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     eth1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c81bfd1d-5dad-4ba0-9160-b6dba7ea325a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
```

Output of `ethtool eth1`:

```
Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
    Link detected: yes
```

Output of `lsmod | grep tg3`:

```
tg3                   164481  0 
ptp                    17692  1 tg3
libphy                 32268  1 tg3
```

Output of `lspci | grep -i ethernet`:

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

Output of `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -i tg`:

```
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.587463] tg3.c:v3.116 (December 3, 2010)
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.587482] tg3 0000:08:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI
 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.587491] tg3 0000:08:00.0: setting latency 
timer to 64
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.604699] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth0: Tigon3 [pa
rtno(BCM95754) rev b002] (PCI Express) MAC address 00:21:9b:41:28:86
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.604702] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth0: attached P
HY is 5787 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1])
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.604704] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth0: RXcsums[1]
 LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [    2.604706] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth0: dma_rwctrl
[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [   13.668551] tg3 0000:08:00.0: irq 78 for MSI/M
SI-X
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [   15.265188] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth1: Link is up
 at 100 Mbps, full duplex
May 15 12:00:14 kernel: [   15.265190] tg3 0000:08:00.0: eth1: Flow contr
ol is off for TX and off for RX
```

output of `ethtool -S eth1`:

```
NIC statistics:
 rx_octets: 1351463
 rx_fragments: 0
 rx_ucast_packets: 0
 rx_mcast_packets: 1051
 rx_bcast_packets: 8167
 rx_fcs_errors: 0
 rx_align_errors: 0
 rx_xon_pause_rcvd: 0
 rx_xoff_pause_rcvd: 0
 rx_mac_ctrl_rcvd: 0
 rx_xoff_entered: 0
 rx_frame_too_long_errors: 0
 rx_jabbers: 0
 rx_undersize_packets: 0
 rx_in_length_errors: 0
 rx_out_length_errors: 0
 rx_64_or_less_octet_packets: 0
 rx_65_to_127_octet_packets: 0
 rx_128_to_255_octet_packets: 0
 rx_256_to_511_octet_packets: 0
 rx_512_to_1023_octet_packets: 0
 rx_1024_to_1522_octet_packets: 0
 rx_1523_to_2047_octet_packets: 0
 rx_2048_to_4095_octet_packets: 0
 rx_4096_to_8191_octet_packets: 0
 rx_8192_to_9022_octet_packets: 0
 tx_octets: 106305
 tx_collisions: 0
 tx_xon_sent: 0
 tx_xoff_sent: 0
 tx_flow_control: 0
 tx_mac_errors: 0
 tx_single_collisions: 0
 tx_mult_collisions: 0
 tx_deferred: 0
 tx_excessive_collisions: 0
 tx_late_collisions: 0
 tx_collide_2times: 0
 tx_collide_3times: 0
 tx_collide_4times: 0
 tx_collide_5times: 0
 tx_collide_6times: 0
 tx_collide_7times: 0
 tx_collide_8times: 0
 tx_collide_9times: 0
 tx_collide_10times: 0
 tx_collide_11times: 0
 tx_collide_12times: 0
 tx_collide_13times: 0
 tx_collide_14times: 0
 tx_collide_15times: 0
 tx_ucast_packets: 492
 tx_mcast_packets: 30
 tx_bcast_packets: 995
 tx_carrier_sense_errors: 0
 tx_discards: 0
 tx_errors: 0
 dma_writeq_full: 0
 dma_write_prioq_full: 0
 rxbds_empty: 0
 rx_discards: 0
 rx_errors: 0
 rx_threshold_hit: 0
 dma_readq_full: 0
 dma_read_prioq_full: 0
 tx_comp_queue_full: 0
 ring_set_send_prod_index: 0
 ring_status_update: 0
 nic_irqs: 0
 nic_avoided_irqs: 0
 nic_tx_threshold_hit: 0
 mbuf_lwm_thresh_hit: 0
```

output of `iptables -vL`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Do the logs have anything to say? Have you tried a different kernel version?

Comment: Which logs? I tried the other kernel available on startup, 3.2.0, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try `/var/log/dmesg`. Debian currently has 4.3 and 4.5 kernel images available. It seems unlikely the kernel is the problem, but it doesn't hurt to try. If you want to hop into the [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat), it might facilitate debugging. You can ping me there if you want.

Comment: I could try different kernel versions, but I'd rather not deviate too much from a standard Stable installation, not to mention that it would logistically cumbersome without Internet.

Comment: You don't happen to have any iptables rules (`iptables -vL` to check) that might be blocking connectivity?

Comment: Or... one other thing that's possible is that eth0 and eth1 are switched around. Are you sure that your cable is in the right port? Easy enough to test: unplug the cable, and make sure ethtool shows the port you expect going down.

Comment: Also, how did you test "there is no connection to the Internet"?

Comment: I added the `iptables` output above

Comment: I checked --the designation of the port is definitely  `eth1`

Comment: Things like `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8`, or anything else I could think of that requires Internet connection, don't work. Though, oddly, `ifconfig eth1` and the Network Tools GUI show a few packets per second being received.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to rewrite resolv.conf at boot time by adding an echo in rc.local , as root type:

```
echo "nameserver ip.addres.of.dns" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

ip.addres.of.dns = ip_router

2)Back up interfaces file

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.copy
```

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

it will be something like (example) :

```
/etc/network/interfaces# This file describes the network interfaces available o$
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 91.121.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 91.121.0.0
    broadcast 91.121.0.255
    gateway 91.121.0.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Update:
for IPV6 an example:

```
  iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8::c0ca:1eaf
    netmask 64
    gateway 2001:db8::1ead:ed:beef
```

Restart the Network:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: Thanks for these ideas.

For (1), could it really be a DNS issue, if there’s no connectivity even just using IP addresses, like in `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8`?

For (2), I already tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` with what I think are the correct settings and restarting, with no luck.

Comment: try to disable ipv6 in kernel: echo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/disableipv6.conf OR  sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=1

Comment: Thanks. Disabling ipv6 doesn't seem to help, even after rebooting.

Comment: try to renew or release an IP to eth0: sudo dhclient -r eth0
and sudo dhclient eth0

Comment: those run with no messages printed, but Internet still doesn't work